# How to update previous view label with NSUserDefault value in iOS, objective c

Tags: objective-c, uilabel, nsuserdefaults

I have two views in my app.in first view there is a label and I want to update it's value in my second view controller(this shows as a popup view). and after second view controller dismissed, the changed value should be in the label(as `lebel.text`). I used `NSUserDefault`.

in my second view controller I assign value like this :

```
- (IBAction)updatetheDatepicker:(id)sender
{
    NSDate *flightDeparturedate = self.flightDepartureDatepicker.date;
    NSDateFormatter *flightdepatureFormatter  = [[NSDateFormatter alloc] init];
    [flightdepatureFormatter setDateFormat:@"d/MM/y"];
    NSString *flightDeparturedateDisplay = [flightdepatureFormatter stringFromDate:flightDeparturedate];

    NSLog(@"selected departure date :%@", flightDeparturedateDisplay);
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setObject:flightDeparturedateDisplay forKey:@"flightDepartureDate"];
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] synchronize];
}
```

and in my `firstviewcontroller` when second view dismiss, I want to update the label in my first view.how can I do that.

```
self.depdate.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"flightDepartureDate"];
```

**NOTE:** second view appears as a `UIPopoverpresentationController`

this is how I popup my second view controller from first view controller

```
- (void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{
    NSString *identifier = segue.identifier;
    if([identifier isEqualToString:@"popover"])
    {
        UIViewController *destinationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        UIPopoverPresentationController *popController = destinationController.popoverPresentationController;
        if(popController)
        {
            popController.delegate = self;
        }
    }

    if([identifier isEqualToString:@"popoverone"])
    {
        UIViewController *destinationController = segue.destinationViewController;
        UIPopoverPresentationController *popController = destinationController.popoverPresentationController;
        if(popController)
        {
            popController.delegate = self;
        }
    }
}


- (UIModalPresentationStyle)adaptivePresentationStyleForPresentationController:(UIPresentationController *)controller
{
    return UIModalPresentationNone;;


}
```

hope your help with this.

Comment: why dont you use the custom delegate ?

Comment: I want to do this with nsuserdefault , isn't it possible

Comment: yes it's possible. Check my Answer.

Answer (score 1):

**NOTE :** Here i did not use any segue. i initiated view controller

FirstViewController.h

```
@interface FirstViewController : UIViewController<UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate>
@property(nonatomic,strong)IBOutlet UILabel *depdate;


@end
```

FirstViewController.m

```
    -(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self updateDateLable];

}

- (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender
{

    //[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"openDatePicker" sender:self];
    UIButton *btnInfo=(UIButton *)sender;
    DatePickerPopUpViewController* popOverFileProperty = [[self storyboard] instantiateViewControllerWithIdentifier:@"DatePickerPopUpViewController"];

    popOverFileProperty.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
    popOverFileProperty.popoverPresentationController.sourceView = btnInfo;
    popOverFileProperty.popoverPresentationController.delegate=self;
    [self presentViewController:popOverFileProperty animated:YES completion:nil];


}


-(void)updateDateLable
{
    if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"flightDepartureDate"] != nil) {
        self.depdate.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"flightDepartureDate"];
    }
    else
    {
        //date is not set yet , set other text as you wish
        self.depdate.text=@"Date not selected";
    }
}


// Called on the delegate when the user has taken action to dismiss the popover. This is not called when the popover is dimissed programatically.
- (void)popoverPresentationControllerDidDismissPopover:(UIPopoverPresentationController *)popoverPresentationController
{
    [self updateDateLable];
}
```

If you want to use Segue :

```
- (IBAction)btnClicked:(id)sender
{

    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"openDatePicker" sender:self];

}

-(void)prepareForSegue:(UIStoryboardSegue *)segue sender:(id)sender
{

    if ([segue.identifier isEqualToString:@"openDatePicker"])
    {
        DatePickerPopUpViewController* popOverFileProperty = [segue destinationViewController];
        popOverFileProperty.modalPresentationStyle = UIModalPresentationPopover;
        popOverFileProperty.popoverPresentationController.delegate=self;

    }
}
```

Comment: this does not work for me. NOTE : first view's viewwillappear or viewdidappear methods does not fire when I come from second view to first view

Comment: uipopovercontroller is deprecated from iOS 9.0, that is why I used another way

Comment: @AnuradhS i updated code and use `UIPopoverPresentationControllerDelegate` for iOS 9 support.

Answer (score 0):

Try to call your update value here from NSUserDefaults.

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated 
 {
 [super viewWillAppear:animated];

if ([[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"flightDepartureDate"] != nil||![[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"flightDepartureDate"]] isEqualToString:@"(null)"]||![[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@",[[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"flightDepartureDate"]] isEqualToString:@""]) {
    self.lbl.text = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] objectForKey:@"flightDepartureDate"];
}
else
    self.lbl.text=@"NO Date..";

 }
```

Comment: this does not work for me.
`NOTE` : first view's `viewwillappear` or `viewdidappear` methods does not fire when I come from second view to first view

Comment: Ok, can you please show me how did you popup your view. Just paste the code here.